# Visible on FindControl not working - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception, on the next line of code:

```
((HyperLink)Page.FindControl(id)).Visible = false;
```

What can be the problem?

Here is a sample from my code:

**.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="FriendsList.aspx.cs" Inherits="Private_User_Social_FriendsList" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<div class="FriendsProposal" runat="server">
<div class="FriendsProposal_Header">FriendsP</div>
<div id="FriendsProposalPH" class="FriendsProposalPH" runat="server"></div>
```

**.aspx.cs:**

```
public partial class Private_User_Social_FriendsList : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DBservices DBS = new DBservices();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        List<Friends> ListFriendsProposal = DBS.getFriendsProposal(User.Identity.Name.ToString());
        foreach (Friends FRIndex in ListFriendsProposal)
        {
            string _FriendsOutput = FR_output(FRIndex);

            HyperLink tempHL = new HyperLink();
            tempHL.Text = _FriendsOutput;
            tempHL.CssClass = "HyperLinkFriends";
            tempHL.ID = FRIndex.UdName;

            FriendsProposalPH.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div style='height:32px' runat='server' >"));
            FriendsProposalPH.Controls.Add(tempHL);

                Button tempApprove = new Button();
                tempApprove.Text = "Approve";
                tempApprove.Click += new EventHandler(cmdUpdate_Click);
                tempApprove.ID = FRIndex.UdName + "1";

                FriendsProposalPH.Controls.Add(tempApprove);
              FriendsProposalPH.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
         }
    }

        private void cmdUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            string _tempID = btn.ID;
            string id = _tempID.Substring(0, _tempID.LastIndexOf('1'));
            DBS.ApproveFriend(User.Identity.Name.ToString(), id);
            btn.Visible = false;
            ((HyperLink)Page.FindControl(id)).Visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: Is Page.FindControl(id) finding the control? Looks like it's returning null...

Comment: Yes, I checked and the Id's exist.

Comment: Just because the id exists it doesn't mean FindControl() can find it. Is it in a master page?

Comment: @Wolf Please explain your question by giving a scenario, what are you doing and where is Hyperlink , are you using master page , Anything that helps.

Comment: I'm trying to make the hyperlink disappear on button click. The hyperlinks and the button created dynamically on page load. I added more code to my question, I hope this will make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're adding the hyperlink to the `FriendsProposalPH` naming container (which is a placeholder control I presume) rather than the `Page` naming container, you should invoke the search method on that naming container and not the page itself (this method only searches within current naming container).

Judging by the code you provided the hyperlink is always added alongside the button, so perhaps the easiest way to access the right naming container and find and hide the hyperlink control is this:

```
btn.NamingContainer.FindControl(id).Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

your control that you are trying to find must have a `runat="server"` attribute or the exact same exception u receive is thrown.

dont forget that asp.net is request-response system, you cant access from the server a client-side controls.

if a control is not running at server, you cannot change it after client received it to his browser.